# All fields with description above the input

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ngx-formly

What is the best way to modify the default wrapper used by every fields?

What I want to achieve is display the description above the fields (by default, for bootstrap, the description appears below the field).

Here is a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-formly-wrapper-description-top

I tried to use wrappers, but I have the following issues:

- Either I have to declare my custom wrapper for every fields (which works but looks quite cumbersome to me)
- Or, If I don't declare the wrapper for the field, both my custom wrapper (configured in the module) and the default wrapper are used, which doubles the display

I would like to find the most elegant solution to use the wrapper for every fields (ideally not only inputs, but selects, radios and so on).

Anyone can help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So, I just discovered that we can also set default options when we create custom types, which offers quite some new possibilities for me:

So the solution is here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-formly-wrapper-description-top-gfj23z

Of course I am open to even better solutions. For instance one which would apply to all field types without having to re-create custom types for each field type.

Hope this helps someone ;-)